# failure to open Rstudio

Tags: rstudio

### R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 2023.09.1+494 "Desert Sunflower " (cd7011dc, 2023-10-16) for macOS

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.09.1+494 Chrome/116.0.5845.190 Electron/26.2.4 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 1.

Error output:

```
[No errors emitted]
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*/Users/lilisprague/.local/share/rstudio/log/rsession-lilisprague.log*

```
2023-12-07T20:43:19.235077Z [rsession-lilisprague] ERROR system error 41 (Protocol wrong type for socket) [request-uri: /grid_data]; OCCURRED AT virtual void rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const core::http::Response &) [ProtocolType = rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp] src/cpp/session/http/SessionPosixHttpConnectionListener.cpp:156; LOGGED FROM: virtual void rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const core::http::Response &) [ProtocolType = rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp] src/cpp/session/http/SessionPosixHttpConnectionListener.cpp:161
2023-12-07T20:47:56.046476Z [rsession-lilisprague] ERROR system error 41 (Protocol wrong type for socket) [request-uri: /grid_data]; OCCURRED AT virtual void rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const core::http::Response &) [ProtocolType = rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp] src/cpp/session/http/SessionPosixHttpConnectionListener.cpp:156; LOGGED FROM: virtual void rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const core::http::Response &) [ProtocolType = rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp] src/cpp/session/http/SessionPosixHttpConnectionListener.cpp:161
2023-12-07T20:47:56.046476Z [rsession-lilisprague] ERROR system error 41 (Protocol wrong type for socket) [request-uri: /grid_data]; OCCURRED AT virtual void rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const core::http::Response &) [ProtocolType = rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp] src/cpp/session/http/SessionPosixHttpConnectionListener.cpp:156; LOGGED FROM: virtual void rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const core::http::Response &) [ProtocolType = rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp] src/cpp/session/http/SessionPosixHttpConnectionListener.cpp:161
```

I opened R and Rstudio and was met with this error

Comment: You'd have better luck by opening your own issue in the RStudio github github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues or post in the RStudio community site: community.rstudio.com. This community is more geared for helping with R code.